# Irrlicht Smesh - Voxel Chunking

Tags: c++, irrlicht

I am trying to recreate the Ogre code used here (in Irrlicht):
http://dave.uesp.net/wiki/Block_Land_3

For this part of the code:

```
MeshChunk->position(x, y,   z+1);   MeshChunk->normal(-1,0,0);  MeshChunk->textureCoord(0, 1);
```

I did this:

```
SMesh* Mesh = new SMesh();

SMeshBuffer *buf = 0;
buf = new SMeshBuffer();


Mesh->addMeshBuffer(buf);

buf->drop();

block_t Block;
block_t Block1;

int iVertex = 0;

buf->Vertices.reallocate(3);
buf->Vertices.set_used(3);
....
buf->Vertices[0] = S3DVertex(vector3df(x, y, z+1), vector3df(-1,0,0), SColor(255, 0,0,0), vector2df(0, 1));
```

But how can this be translated:

```
MeshChunk->triangle(iVertex, iVertex+1, iVertex+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's adding indices, specifically a set of 3 vertex indexes;

```
buf->Vertices[0] = S3DVertex(vector3df(x, y, z+1), vector3df(-1,0,0), SColor(255, 0,0,0), vector2df(0, 1));
buf->Vertices[1] = S3DVertex(vector3df(x, y+1, z+1), vector3df(-1,0,0), SColor(255, 0,0,0), vector2df(0, 1));
buf->Vertices[2] = S3DVertex(vector3df(x, y+1, z), vector3df(-1,0,0), SColor(255, 0,0,0), vector2df(0, 1));
buf->Vertices[3] = S3DVertex(vector3df(x, y, z), vector3df(-1,0,0), SColor(255, 0,0,0), vector2df(0, 1));


buf->Indices.push_back(0);
buf->Indices.push_back(1);
buf->Indices.push_back(2);
//MeshChunk->triangle(iVertex, iVertex+1, iVertex+2);

buf->Indices.push_back(2);
buf->Indices.push_back(3);
buf->Indices.push_back(0);
//MeshChunk->triangle(iVertex+2, iVertex+3, iVertex);
```

Verticies is a list of positions, Indices shows the order in which to use them (based on their position in Verticies).

You can reuse indexes of Verticies if triangles share points - this will make the border between triangles soft if the triangles are not co-planar, or you can create multiple verticies at the same position, allowing for a hard-edge.